# how to get recent data from entries in dart flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making some entries and now i want to fetch recent entries based on a field

Like i have list of available Games.. and now i want to fatch recent **3 unique games** from last entries..and want to show this three games in top of list and all other **remaining games in sorted a->z order**....

here is my code

```
void main() {
  List<String> allGames = [
    'Football',
    'Cricket',
    'Tennis',
    'Hockey',
    'Baseball',
    'Race',
    'Swimming',
    'Polo',
    'Rugby',
    'Puzzle',
    'Soccer',
  ];
  List<String> recentGames = [
    'Football',
    'Football',
    'Cricket',
    'Football',
    'Soccer',
    'Football',
    'Football',
    'Soccer',
    'Cricket',
    'Puzzle',
    'Puzzle'
  ];

  //1  )first of all i want only first 3 unique Games from recentGames
  // List<String> recent3= Football  Cricket Soccer

  //2  ) now want to merge all remaining games with recent3 games
  //like remainingGames=allGames-recent3 ,sorted in A-> Z
  // remainingGames= BaseBall Hockey Polo Race Rugby Swimming Tennis

  //3) merge recent3+ remainingGames
  // resultGames=Football Cricket Soccer Baseball Hockey Polo Race Rugby Swimming Tennis;

  List<String> resultGames = [];

  // logic code

  print(resultGames);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To get the first 3 unique games from recentGames

```dart
    ///
    /// `toSet()` to make sure the List has no duplicate value
    ///
    List<String> recent3 = recentGames.toSet().take(3).toList();
```

2. To find the remaining games and sort them alphabetically

```dart
    ///
    /// `sort()` by default in ASC alphabetical order
    ///
    List<String> remainingGames = allGames..addAll(recent3)
                                          ..sort()
                                          ..toList();
```

3

```dart
    ///
    /// `...` spread operator to expand iterable data to list
    ///
    List<String> resultGames =  [...recent3, ...remainingGames].toSet().toList();
```

- Output (p.s. I use logger package to print this output)

```
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│  [<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Football",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Cricket",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Soccer",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Baseball",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Hockey",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Polo",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Puzzle",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Race",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Rugby",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Swimming",<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│    "Tennis"<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;12m│  ]<…>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962693/failing-to-set-value-while-using-providers-constructor-in-flutter pls check this question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to achieve the following steps:

1. Get the first 3 unique games from the `recentGames` list.
2. Find the remaining games by subtracting the recent games from the `allGames` list and sort them alphabetically.
3. Merge the recent games with the remaining games.

Here's the code to achieve this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> allGames = [
    'Football',
    'Cricket',
    'Tennis',
    'Hockey',
    'Baseball',
    'Race',
    'Swimming',
    'Polo',
    'Rugby',
    'Puzzle',
    'Soccer',
  ];
  List<String> recentGames = [
    'Football',
    'Football',
    'Cricket',
    'Football',
    'Soccer',
    'Football',
    'Football',
    'Soccer',
    'Cricket',
    'Puzzle',
    'Puzzle',
  ];

  // Step 1: Get the first 3 unique games from recentGames
  Set<String> uniqueRecentGames = {};
  List<String> recent3 = [];
  for (String game in recentGames) {
    if (!uniqueRecentGames.contains(game)) {
      uniqueRecentGames.add(game);
      recent3.add(game);
      if (recent3.length >= 3) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Step 2: Find remaining games and sort them alphabetically
  List<String> remainingGames = List.from(allGames);
  remainingGames.removeWhere((game) => recent3.contains(game));
  remainingGames.sort();

  // Step 3: Merge recent3 and remainingGames
  List<String> resultGames = [...recent3, ...remainingGames];

  print(resultGames);
}
```

This code will give you the desired output where the first 3 unique recent games are followed by the remaining games in alphabetical order.

Comment: hi pls can u check this question..basic but cant understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962693/failing-to-set-value-while-using-providers-constructor-in-flutter